# How to swap elements with animations

Tags: javascript, css-animations

There are several suggestions here on SO for swapping elements in the DOM, in particular when elements have different parents. Two I have tried are as follows:

```
swap1(a,b) 
{
    const aParent = a.parentNode;
    const bParent = b.parentNode;

    var aHolder = document.createElement("div");
    var bHolder = document.createElement("div");

    aParent.replaceChild(aHolder,a);
    bParent.replaceChild(bHolder,b);
    aParent.replaceChild(b,aHolder);
    bParent.replaceChild(a,bHolder);
}
```

and

```
swap2(a,b) 
{
    const parent1 = a.parentNode;
    const parent2 = b.parentNode;
    var next2 = b.nextSibling;
    // special case for a is the next sibling of b
    if (next2 === a) {
        // just put a before b
        parent2.insertBefore(a, b);
        Draggable.log('next sibling');
    } else {
        // insert b right before a
        parent1.insertBefore(b, a);
        // now insert obj1 where obj2 was
        if (next2) {
         // if there was an element after b, then insert a right before that
            parent2.insertBefore(a, next2);
        } else {
            // otherwise, just append as last child
            parent2.appendChild(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these appeared to work, although sometimes I experienced odd errors where the parent nodes would end up with the wrong number of elements. I then added an animation to the swapped elements, and the problems occurred a *lot more* (almost every time).

The error is generally `"Node.replaceChild: Child to be replaced is not a child of this node"`, or similar, depending on the method used.

After doing a  bit of research, I came across some posts suggesting a timeout between moving elements, to allow the first move to complete before the second was started. So I tried this:

```
swap3(a,b) 
{
    const aParent = a.parentNode;
    const bParent = b.parentNode;

    var aHolder = document.createElement("div");
    var bHolder = document.createElement("div");

    aParent.replaceChild(aHolder,a);
    setTimeout(function() {
        bParent.replaceChild(bHolder,b);
        setTimeout(function() {
            aParent.replaceChild(b,aHolder);
            setTimeout(function() {
                bParent.replaceChild(a,bHolder);
            }, 0);
        }, 0);
    }, 0);
}
```

But it helped very little. Setting the timeouts to *longer than I knew the animations took*, the problem was 'solved' but:

- The messy semi-changed state of the DOM was shown to the user long enough to see; it looked horrible!, and
- I am writing this code for a library, which won't know if elements have animations, or if so how long they take.

Any suggestions to make this work smoothly?

Comment: Why not just dynamically edit the source a tribute?

Comment: Do you mean remove the animation class before the move, and add it again afterwards? The library won't know what classes to look for - unless there is a way? Also, as I noted, occasionally the method fails even without animations, presumably when the DOM change is a bit slow?

Comment: Your aholder and bholder divs. Instead of replacing them with each other just have one div that has its content dynamically changed.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem in the past, the problem was not the swapping per se, but the fact that we were swapping live elements. The safest approach, in this case, is to clone the elements, swap them, and then replace all of them (or possibly just the affected ones).

It's a timing problem, not a swapping problem. My guess is that would work smoothly in react or vue because all the elements are re-rendered when the order changes, at the end of the computation.

Here's an example of code to swap cloning:

```
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.elementsToClone');
let clonedElementsContainer = document.createElement("div");
elems.forEach(el => {
    let clone = el.cloneNode(true);        
    clonedElementsContainer.appendChild(clone);
}
// do your rearranging here
document.querySelector('.oldElementsContainer').replaceWith(clonedElementsContainer);
```

Alternatively, switching to shadow DOM would allow you to switch between states (to-be-ordered and after-being-ordered for instance) and re-render at will.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried using `cloneNode` but it gave the same problem. Shadow DOM sounds interesting, but it's a new subject for me so I need to explore it a bit - or maybe you can help by decorating your answer with some code?

Comment: It seems weird that cloning doesn't work, I added a code sample for that. Shadow DOM is very interesting but it is definitely not super easy, and it would only work if you basically re-created elements under shadow DOM, replacing the originals. It also basically has a "scoped" CSS, which means that it will require additional work on that side. It is maybe overkill for this use case. But cloning elements should definitely work. If you replace the whole container, the elements shouldn't behave weirdly.

Comment: Thanks again but this just gets too complex when elements have different parents. See my attempt - maybe I didn't understand you correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, in my case, some of the parent's children are *not* draggable elements. This means that, for example, the test `if (next2) {` of the second example leads to errors, becuase of instead of returning `null` it returns an invalid element that shouldn't be swapped.
For some reason adding the animation delays made the results of the error much easier to see.

So I have added further tests, and a new class, to check which elements should be 'next to' and 'previous to' the ones being swapped:

```
    const parent1 = obj1.parentNode;
    const parent2 = obj2.parentNode;
    const next2 = obj2.nextElementSibling;
    const prev2 = obj2.previousElementSibling;
    // special case for obj1 is the next sibling of obj2
    if (next2 === obj1) {
        // just put obj1 before obj2
        parent2.insertBefore(obj1, obj2);
    } else {
        // insert obj2 right before obj1
        parent1.insertBefore(obj2, obj1);
        if (next2 != null && next2.classList.contains('dragGroup')) {
            // if there was an element after obj2, then insert obj1 right before that
            parent2.insertBefore(obj1, next2);

        } else if (prev2 != null && prev2.classList.contains('dragGroup')) {
            // effectively 'insertAfter' - see docs
            parent2.insertBefore(obj1, prev2.nextElementSibling);
        } else {
           Draggable.log('nowhere to drag!');
           return false;
        }
    }
```

The debugger shows that very occasionally the function returns `false`; how often depends (oddly) on the type of animation used. But by returning false, the swap can be aborted and everything stays in the correct place.

A `translate' animation, e.g.

```
@keyframes bounce {
  ....
  40% { transform:translateY(-15%); }
  ....
}
```

never appeas to make to above function return `false`, but a `scale' animation, e.g.

```
@keyframes myBounce {
  ....
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
  ....
}
```

makes it return `false` quite often. Both aninations make the elements' images grow into adjacent placeholders temporarily, so I don't understand the difference. I'm sticking with the `translate`  method for safety.